# Is there an expression for a principle that is only a first approximation?

Tags: word-choice

Is there an expression for a principle that is a close approximation to the truth, but quite possibly has exceptions? For example, "Do not kill". This is a good first approximation, but almost everyone would make allow except for self defense.

I don't like the word "general", because it is often used in the sense of meaning universal, such as "The general theory of relativity".

I don't like "first approximation" or "heuristic", as they could be unfamiliar to people without a scientific background.

UPDATE: Another word I though of is "preliminary"

Comment: The example you choose is itself worthy of analysis! Though the AV (KJV) of the Bible reads 'Thou shalt not kill', this translation apparently does not accurately reflect the true meaning of the original Hebrew. See, for example, http://www.godandscience.org/apologetics/notkill.   Modern translations, with 'You shall not (commit) murder', come far closer - but an unwieldy 'Do not kill unless you have a cast-iron reason to do so' is probably better still. There is still the small matter of deciding what constitutes a cast-iron reason!

Comment: Oh, and there is the general principle in the Bible that a 'rule' often has to be carefully applied so as not to be used as an excuse to break another rule. So, a person claiming to be God should be stoned to death (**not** crucified). **Unless** He's actually telling the truth. There is even a term used to describe the apparent contradictions that appear in the Bible when laws, at first sight, conflict: antinomies. Also, when Jesus subsumes stark Old Testament laws into teachings allowing grace ('You have heard it said ... but I say ...') (Matt 5), these are known as antithetical teachings.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This very point is debated frequently over at Christianity.SE.  It essentially comes down to the different between murder and killing being that when the lawgiver gives a special exemption for the former, it becomes the latter.  So there's really no difference between the two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be able to use ***rule of thumb***.  NOAD says:

> **rule of thumb**: *a broadly accurate guide or principle, based on experience or practice rather than theory*.

Other definitions listed on [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/rule%20of%20thumb) include:

> *A useful principle having wide application but not intended to be strictly accurate or reliable in every situation*.
>
> *A general guideline, rather than a strict rule; an approximate measure or means of reckoning based on experience or common knowledge*.

Those definitions seem to fit your request for “a close approximation to the truth, but quite possibly [having] exceptions.”

Comment: +1, the second definition given has the word I would choose, which is *guideline*.

Comment: Provisional guideline could work well in many circumstances

Comment: While I agree totally with this answer, it does seem rather incongruous to apply it to Casebash's example - **The Ten Rules of Thumb**.

Comment: @Edwin: I almost mentioned that when I answered – how "rule of thumb" might not be the best way to describe a sentiment like "do not kill."  As to your other point, though, even commandments sometimes have exceptions – see [Ezekiel 9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel%209:5-7&version=NKJV), e.g.

Answer (score 2):

I'd refer to such principles, or not-quite principles, by adjectives like the following.
• *[rudimentary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rudimentary#Adjective)*, “of or relating to one or more rudiments [eg] I have only a rudimentary grasp of chemistry”; “Basic; minimal; with less than, or only the minimum, necessary”
• *[inchoate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inchoate#Adjective)*, “Recently started but not fully formed yet; just begun; only elementary or immature”; “Chaotic, disordered, confused; also, incoherent, rambling”
• *[nascent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nascent#Adjective)*, “Emerging; just coming into existence”
• *[primitive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/primitive#Adjective)*, which has senses that include primordial, primeval, characterized by simplicity

Of the above, *rudimentary* and *primitive* have the widest applicability to not-quite principles.  The other terms may apply well to not-yet-perfected principles that are being developed or revealed little by little, by continuing work, research, or experience.

Answer (score 1):

*Initial hypothesis*? Or just *hypothesis* on its own. As it is expected to be refined anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there's an intrinsic difference between a [rule](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rule) and a [principle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principle). While the two are often used interchangeably, a *rule* is more like a *regulation* or a *guideline* while a *principle* imports something more *fundamental*. In any event, here are a few alternative suggestions.

While it may not suggest an *approximation* as such, **core** implies that there might be something more (the flesh?) to be considered.

Other choices:

- **nutshell**, *in a nutshell*, or *nutshell version*
- **bare-bones**
- **pith** or *pithy*
- **concise**

Then, *depending on context*, there is also **basic** (or *basis*) which suggest a *base* upon which something is built.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with *core* or *fundamental* principle.

Comment: Core or fundamental principles are generally ones that can't be compromised

Comment: @casebash I'm not aware of that definition. There's no mention of compromise at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fundamental+principle. In any case that wouldn't make my answer incorrect as the fundamental principle shouldn't be compromised by any refinements.